# MySQL database seems more restricted in later version

Tags: mysql, version

I have two tables, contacts and auth, which are linked together with a foreign key, contact_id. When I try to delete a record from the contact table, it gives me an error as follows: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`globalpl_pbcert_db`.`auth`, CONSTRAINT `auth_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_id`) REFERENCES `contacts` (`contact_id`)).
I don't get this message when I delete a contact on my machine, only on the client's server.
the versions are different. his is more advanced.
I don't have cpanel access and I can only make changes to the database using rawmysql (or to the code itself).
I'm considering running the following query, to alter the key and basically remove the restriction.

```
"ALTER TABLE auth DROP FOREIGN KEY auth_ibfk_2; ALTER TABLE auth ADD CONSTRAINT auth_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (contact_id) REFERENCES contacts (contact_id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE RESTRICT;"
```

can this cause any harm to my database. because of my limited access, I'm wary of running a query that will mess things up.
I don't have very much experience with databases.
Here are images showing the structure of the auth table, the contacts table and the foreign keys for the former.
Here's the output for SHOW CREATE TABLE:

```
auth table
Array ( [Table] => auth [Create Table] => CREATE TABLE `auth` ( `token` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `ip` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `expiry` datetime NOT NULL, `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `contact_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `company_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, KEY `contact_id` (`contact_id`) USING BTREE, KEY `company_id` (`company_id`) USING BTREE, KEY `user_id` (`user_id`) USING BTREE, KEY `token` (`token`) USING BTREE, CONSTRAINT `auth_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`), CONSTRAINT `auth_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_id`) REFERENCES `contacts` (`contact_id`), CONSTRAINT `contacts_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `contacts` (`company_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 )
```

companies table

```
Array ( [Table] => companies [Create Table] => CREATE TABLE `companies` ( `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `company_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `company_code` int(11) NOT NULL, `company_address1` varchar(255) DEFAULT '', `company_address2` varchar(255) DEFAULT '', `company_city` varchar(255) DEFAULT '', `company_province` varchar(255) DEFAULT '', `company_postal_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT '', `company_country` varchar(255) DEFAULT '', `company_phone` varchar(255) DEFAULT '', `company_fax` varchar(255) DEFAULT '', `company_email` varchar(255) DEFAULT '', `company_website` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'www.', `company_note` varchar(255) DEFAULT '', PRIMARY KEY (`company_id`), UNIQUE KEY `company_code` (`company_code`) USING BTREE ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=60 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 )
```

contacts table

```
Array ( [Table] => contacts [Create Table] => CREATE TABLE `contacts` ( `contact_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `contact_first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', `contact_last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', `contact_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', `contact_phone` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', `contact_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', `contact_username` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', `contact_password` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`contact_id`), KEY `company_id` (`company_id`), CONSTRAINT `contacts_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `companies` (`company_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 )
```

facilities table

```
Array ( [Table] => facilities [Create Table] => CREATE TABLE `facilities` ( `facility_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `facility_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `facility_address1` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `facility_address2` varchar(255) DEFAULT '', `facility_city` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `facility_province` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `facility_postal_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `facility_country` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `facility_phone` varchar(255) DEFAULT '', `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`facility_id`), KEY `company_id` (`company_id`) USING BTREE, CONSTRAINT `facilities_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `companies` (`company_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 )
```

formulas

```
Array ( [Table] => formulas [Create Table] => CREATE TABLE `formulas` ( `formulas_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL, `ingredient_id` int(11) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`formulas_id`), KEY `product_id` (`product_id`), KEY `ingredient_id` (`ingredient_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 )
```

ingredients

```
Array ( [Table] => ingredients [Create Table] => CREATE TABLE `ingredients` ( `ingredient_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `ingredient_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `ingredient_eval_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL, `ingredient_eval_date` date DEFAULT NULL, `ingredient_note` text, `vendor_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`ingredient_id`), KEY `company_id` (`company_id`) USING BTREE, KEY `user_id` (`user_id`) USING BTREE, CONSTRAINT `ingredients_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `companies` (`company_id`), CONSTRAINT `ingredients_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=72 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 )
```

pl_companies

```
Array ( [Table] => pl_companies [Create Table] => CREATE TABLE `pl_companies` ( `pl_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `pl_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `pl_address1` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `pl_address2` varchar(255) DEFAULT '', `pl_city` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `pl_province` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `pl_postal_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `pl_country` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `pl_phone` varchar(255) DEFAULT '', `pl_fax` varchar(255) DEFAULT '', `pl_email` varchar(255) DEFAULT '', `pl_website` varchar(255) DEFAULT '', `pl_brand` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`pl_id`), KEY `company_id` (`company_id`) USING BTREE, CONSTRAINT `pl_companies_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `companies` (`company_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 )
```

products

```
Array ( [Table] => products [Create Table] => CREATE TABLE `products` ( `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `product_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `product_brand` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `product_eval_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL, `product_eval_date` date DEFAULT NULL, `product_note` text, `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL, `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `facility_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `pl_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`), KEY `company_id` (`company_id`) USING BTREE, KEY `user_id` (`user_id`) USING BTREE, KEY `facility_id` (`facility_id`) USING BTREE, KEY `pl_id` (`pl_id`) USING BTREE ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 )
```

users

```
Array ( [Table] => products [Create Table] => CREATE TABLE `products` ( `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `product_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `product_brand` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `product_eval_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL, `product_eval_date` date DEFAULT NULL, `product_note` text, `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL, `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `facility_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `pl_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`), KEY `company_id` (`company_id`) USING BTREE, KEY `user_id` (`user_id`) USING BTREE, KEY `facility_id` (`facility_id`) USING BTREE, KEY `pl_id` (`pl_id`) USING BTREE ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 )
```

[image: auth table structure]
[image: contacts table structure]
[image: foreign keys for auth]

Comment: Please add the output from show create table <tablename> for all tables on all servers. BTW mysql version changes won't be the reason for this problem which implies your schemas are not the same.

Comment: I added the output @P.Salmon